# How to make a chatterbot using scheme that substitutes certain words to different words?

Tags: scheme

I'm having a hard time starting this exact problem. Here are the directions for this problems.

- ****Part 4: substitutebot-creator In addition to being able to match
  parts of a sentence, a ChatterBot should change the meaning of what
  it says depending on your input. Write a procedure called
  substitutebot-creator that takes in two same-length sentences, FROM
  and TO, and outputs a ChatterBot. The first item of FROM and TO are
  associated, as are the second two items, the third, etc. The
  outputted ChatterBot will take in a sentence, SENT, and output a new
  sentence where every word in SENT that is a member of FROM is
  replaced with its corresponding word in TO. If FROM and TO are empty
  sentences, the ChatterBot will simply return SENT****

Examples:

```
    STK> (define marions-vacay
      (substitutebot-creator '(indonesia winter noodles)
                             '(texas summer steak)))
    STK> (marions-vacay '(i visited indonesia this winter and ate noodles))
(i visited texas this summer and ate steak)
```

I've tried to use the following:

```
  (define (substitutebot-creator from to)
  (lambda (x) (substitutebot x from to)))

  (define (substitutebot sent from to)
  (define subby? (lambda (word) (equal? (recurse-first from) word)))
  (cond ((and (empty? from)(empty? to)) sent)
        ((subby? (first sent))
        (se (recurse-switch (first sent) from to
        (count from)) (substitutebot (bf sent))))
(else (substitutebot (bf sent)))))

        (define (recurse-first sent)
   (if (empty? sent)
   '()
   ((word(first sent))(recurse-first (bf sent)))))
```

But it doesn't work. I think I'm starting this problem on the wrong path, so I would like to know what is the best way to start this problem. Pretty much how do I successfully make a chatbot create another chatbot.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to keep your thought as simple as possible. The point of the problem is that you need to make a dictionary and look it up by given word. For this purpose, you can use alist (association list).

For more concrete hints:

1. Creates an alist with the following structure: `((before . after) ...)`
2. Go through the given word of list and lookup above alist (with `assq` is enough).

Answer (score 0):

I can get you started using `fold-left`

```
(define (make-alist from to)
   (fold-left (lambda (acc from to) (cons (cons from to) acc)) '() from to))

(make-alist '(indonesia winter noodles) '(texas summer steak)) => ((noodles . steak) (winter . summer) (indonesia . texas))
```

then you can use `assq` on the result of `make-alist`